# CentOS/yum - Upgrading php 5.1 -> 5.3 without upgrading mysql 5.0 -> 5.1

Tags: mysql, php, centos5, yum

I'm attempting to upgrade php from the centos default of 5.1.6 to 5.3.8 out of the Atomic repo, but when doing so, yum wants mysql to upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1, saying that php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5 is dependant on mysql 5.1 (5.1.59-1.el5.art).

Is there any way to keep these packages in the package manager, or is this just a unavoidable facet of yum/rpms? will we need to compile php/mysql from source? This is a box running plesk parallels management 9, if that makes a difference, though to my knowledge, it shouldn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally no one will compile php in a Plesk server. You can disable atomic repo and install php 5.3 using the php53 packages provided in the default centos repo itself. Note that the php version is 5.3.3 and you can use the default packages if that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

take the src.rpm they provide and build that on your box like

```
rpmbuild -ba php.spec
```

That will build php 5.3.8 rpms for your version of mysql

Comment: are you referring to srpms provided by atomic? I'm still looking but having trouble finding them. (nevermind, I found them)

Comment: I guess http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/source/php/php-5.3.8-1.art.src.rpm is what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry for the noob questions, but installing this wouldn't do anything about all the extensions the client has installed, would it?  e.g. php-xml-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3

even if I used rpmbuild to create the proper rpms, wouldn't there still be complaints about dependencies? Especially because there seem to be a lot of plesk rpms that depend on php.

Comment: the spec file once built will build all the php-* files you already have on your system